# Windows Azure Linux VM, teredo tunnel and squid proxy

Tags: squid, ipv6, azure

I have teredo working so that I can ping VM via ipv6, squid3 is also working fine but only via ipv4. I made two endpoints (tcp and udp) to the proxy (port 8888) on the Azure site. What should I do now to make the port accessible via ipv6?

Answer (score 1):

Teredo is not suitable for server/service deployment. If you want your server to be reachable over IPv6 then either get native connectivity, or else use a reliable tunnel from i.e. tunnelbroker.net.

Comment: I can't create a tunnel because Azure doesn't allow ICMP ping. Is it even possible to make Azure VM reachable via IPv6 somehow?

Comment: Probably not then. Stupid that they even block ping, but unfortunately some people still think ping is dangerous instead of useful...